# How to provide a visual breakdown of the liquor category in this R code

Tags: r, statistics, r-markdown

I used the following code to upload my data on R

```
if (!file.exists("ames-liquor.rds")) {
  url <- "https://github.com/ds202-at-ISU/materials/blob/master/03_tidyverse/data/ames-liquor.rds?raw=TRUE"
  download.file(url, "ames-liquor.rds", mode="wb")
}
data <- readRDS("ames-liquor.rds")
```

Then use this code to extract geographic latitude and longitude

```
ata <- data %>% 
  separate(remove= FALSE,
           col = 'Store Location' , sep=" ",
           into=c("toss-it", "Latitude", "Longitude"))
data <- data %>% mutate(
  Latitude = parse_number(Latitude),
  Longitude = parse_number(Longitude)
)
```

Now I needed to

```
Plot a scatterplot of lat and long of store locations. 
  - Provide a visual breakdown of the liquor category (by `Category Name`). Include volume sold in the breakdown. Make sure that all labels are readable
```

for the first part of it I did this

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Latitude, y = Longitude))+
  geom_point(na.rm = TRUE)
```

But I cant seem to find how to

```
  - Provide a visual breakdown of the liquor category (by `Category Name`). Include volume sold in the breakdown. Make sure that all labels are readable.
```

I would really appreciate your help

Comment: Add ```color = `Category Name` ``` inside the `aes()` section of the `ggplot` call.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to provide another variable to the aesthetic that gets the color into the labels like so:

data %>%
ggplot(aes(x = Latitude, y = Longitude, color=`Category Name`, size=`Volume Sold (Liters)`))+
geom_point(na.rm = TRUE)

This will provide colors and should tell `ggplot2` to add a legend.

EDIT: I moved size to the aes() in ggplot. I get it to make something but I have a tiny laptop screen and with 130+ unique Category Names all I see is the legend.

It should plot now, but you will need to think through pulling out reasonable sets of categories and make multiple plots

Comment: Thank you so much but then how can I Include volume sold in the breakdown?

Comment: I just updated it with the `size=volume` your field may have another name, but using that will vary the size of the map dot to account for the proportion of sales volume!

Comment: its interesting I have the same mapping as yours but this is what I get

Comment: Error in layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomPoint, : 
object 'volume' not found